# Having troubles accessing elements crawling steam

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



url = 'https://store.steampowered.com'
content = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
priceList = []
z = 0

for listing in content.find_all('div', {'class': 'hero_data'}):

    game_name = listing.find('div', {'class' : 'hero_name'}).text
    developer = listing.find('div', {'class': 'hero_stat'}).text
    for listing in content.find_all('div', {'class': 'discount_block discount_block_inline hero_discount'}):
        priceList.append(listing.find('div', {'class': 'discount_final_price'}).text)

    print(game_name)
    print(developer)
    print(priceList[z])
    z += 1
```

Im trying to crawl steam finding every games name, developer, price, publisher and review crawling it with bs4. Right now i have the name, developer and price set. However, for the publisher and review since they are both listed the same as the developer which is  when i try to access them by its class, it just gives me the first one in the html which is the developer.

Comment: Why do you have double equal here:
price = publisher = listing.find( ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reassignment inside this for loop:

```
for listing in content.find_all('div', {'class': 'discount_block discount_block_inline 
    hero_discount'}):
    price = listing.find('div', {'class': 'discount_final_price'}).text
```

You are overwritting price and publisher for every iteration. Price is holding the last value of the iteration. If you want to show every price, you better create a list and append every price to it.

```
priceList = []
for listing in content.find_all('div', {'class': 'discount_block discount_block_inline 
    hero_discount'}):
    priceList.append(listing.find('div', {'class': 'discount_final_price'}).text)
```

Edit:
As there are more than one element with the 'hero_stat' attribute, you will have to store them on a list too, using findAll:

```
stats = list(map(lambda stat: stat.text, listing.find_all('div', {'class': 'hero_stat'})))   # this is a list
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Your code helped me find the price, i still cant find a way to access the publisher and reviews, in the steam html they are both listed as <div class="hero_stat"> so when i access that class, it takes developer which is the first of three listed as <div class="hero_stat">